# Show custom field in comment/response interface (RT)

Tags: customization, rt

I've created a **custom field** in order to detail what person's answer I'm waiting for.

Just an combo box that **needs to apply to a ticket** (queue or transaction doesn't work for me, because I need to filter the tickets using this field).

Now, I send a comment asking for something and I need to go all the way to the custom fields form to complete the field 'waiting for'. This is very tedious.

**I would like to fill my custom field in the comment interface**, under the *ticket and transaction* or *message* menu.

I've looked in RT documentation but I couldn't find anything similar (except changing the custom field to apply on transaction).

Answer (score 2):

The "natural" way is to use the `Jumbo` link to update the whole ticket. Or you can install the [CustomFieldsOnUpdate extension](https://metacpan.org/pod/RT::Extension::CustomFieldsOnUpdate).

Comment: When I'm closing the ticket I need the email field as shown on 'resolved' menu (with cc/cco fields, comment with and without final user, etc). And I need a simple interface, because the other fields were filled when I opened the ticket.
The 'natural' way on Resolve is the resolve menu.

I'm gonna try with the plugin. Thanks for your answer :)